# Search for a certain item and click another item related to it?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I want to let selenium search for the `final_new building` row and go to the version on the right and click it.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTQnF.png) you'll find a picture of my problem.

As you see in the left side of the picture (arrow tail) there is a certain expression which is `final_new building`.

I want the selenium webdriver to search for this text and if found, it should click on the number in the right side (arrow top) - whatever the number is, just click it.

Any idea/guidelines welcome, thanks.

Comment: Add html source in text format

Comment: Update the question with HTML code.

Comment: Assume the grid in your picture complement by `table/tr/td` tags, you can use following xpath to archive your goal: `//tr[ td[3] [text()='Final-New Build'] ]/td[6]/a`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**Why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Without accessing the HTML and understanding the relationship between the elements, it is not possible to provide a specific answer.

However, XPath allows you access siblings (https://www.guru99.com/using-contains-sbiling-ancestor-to-find-element-in-selenium.html), and that may be a useful tool in this case